# How do I get URL from currently opened chrome window using python?

Tags: python

I am using **`Python Script`** to download videos from web in order to get actual video URL. I am using package "**`beautifulsoup`**" and it works. Input to `**beautifulsoup**` is URL of website, as of now I am copying and pasting it from browser.

**Query**

How to get this URL of web using **`Python`**? So that there will not be need of copy and paste every time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Selenium Webdriver since it acts as a browser and makes it easy for you to do user actions like getting the current URL. Here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

executable_path = "/usr/bin/geckodriver"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=executable_path)
browser.get('http://google.com')
print(browser.current_url) ## here is your current url
```